# How to decide whether to increase the number of asyncio aiohttp process?

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'd like to use asyncio aiohttp to build a web application that must scale over a dozen of processus?

How do I decide to increase the number of asyncio process?

Should I monitor IO or CPU and decide on that?

Answer (score 1):

When you run your `aiohttp` server it'll serve all incoming requests using all available  HDD/RAM/network resources and CPU core's it's running on resources.

If you have multiple CPU cores on your machine, the best way is to run `aiohttp` behind `nginx` and configure it to utilize all cores (read more [here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/deployment.html#nginx-supervisord)). It'll allow you to utilize all avaliable machine's resources without need to tune something else manually. Plus `nginx` will serve static files much better then pure `aiohttp`.

I think above will do more than fine if you doesn't have very high loaded app.

Otherwise you can still face limit of current machine's resources. You should then detect where is the bottleneck (is it HDD, RAM, CPU, network capacity?) and decide which solution to choose:

- Increase current machine resources ("Vertical scaling")
- Run app on multiple machines ("Horizontal scaling")
- Optimize your app code ("profiling" + "optimization")

Each way above is a huge separate topic.